# how to add some more functionality to inbuilt php functions

Tags: php

I am working on a PHP project. This project is using mysql_fetch_array many places.

now. I want to sanitize data. So I want that after php function mysql_fetch_array is called. My function to sanitize data should be called. I don't want to call my function in each of its call. because this call will be at more than 400 places.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Rewrite PHP core; or perhaps switch to using MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements/bind variables; or create a wrapper for your queries

Answer (score 2):

You can't amend the PHP core functions because  your project  will not work under other php versions.

A good approach is to find & replace "mysql_fetch_array()" to your function in whole project then add what you want :)

Comment: Actually we dont want change in many files. Because it requires testing of all that changes.

Comment: Already you need to test all affected places. and there no ability to change or overwrite php built in functions